# How to convert json into json array in pgsql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I face some issue to convert the data into json object. There is a table called milestone with the following data:

```
id  name    parentId
a   test1   A
b   test2   B
c   test3   C
d   test4   A
e   test5   B
```

I want to convert the result into a json type in Postgres:

```
content(json type)                                                         parentId
"assignees": [{"id": "a", "name": "test1"},{"id": "d", "name": "test4"}]   A
"assignees": [{"id": "b", "name": "test2"},{"id": "e", "name": "test5"}]   B
"assignees": [{"id": "c", "name": "test3"}]                                C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_build_object()` to create the id/name pairs, and then aggregate that into an array using `jsonb_agg()`:

```
select parentid, 
       jsonb_build_object('assignees', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', id, 'name', name)))
from milestone
group by parentid
order by parentid;
```

---

If you don't want to repeat the column names, or if you have more columns than you have shown you could also use `to_jsonb()` and then remove the `parentid`:

```
select m.parentid, 
       jsonb_build_object('assignees', jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(m) - 'parentid')))
from milestone m
group by m.parentid
order by m.parentid;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/JXVFF71777